# Posting nested object to nodejs server via ajax is returning undefined

Tags: ajax, node.js, body-parser

I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours already but I can't seem to find the cause of the issue.

On the client-side Javascript I'm posting a nested object via ajax to my backend nodejs server. The ajax looks like this:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/user/save",
  data: {
    "account": {
      "username": $signupForm.find("input[name='register_username']").val(),
      "email": $signupForm.find("input[name='register_email']").val(),
      "password": $signupForm.find("input[name='register_password']").val(),
      "plan": subscription
    },
    "stripe": stripeResponse
  },
  dataType: "json",
  beforeSend: function(){
    $.fn.showLoading();
  },
  success: function(data){

  }
});
```

Then I catch this in my routes/index.js

```js
router.post('/user/save', function(req, res){
  var post_data = req.body;
  console.info(post_data);

  var account = post_data.account;
  var card = post_data.stripe;

  console.log(account);
  console.log(card);

  // Rest of code...
```

The problem here now is that for some reason, both `post_data.account` and `post_data.stripe` are returned as undefined. post_data itself does indeed return the data.

I also tried sending the data from ajax using `JSON.stringify` but that didn't work as well.

I also have body-parser required and in use under app.js

I can't see where my problem is. Why is my data undefined?

Comment: What does `console.info(post_data)` say?

Comment: @JohnWhite `console.info(post_data)` returns the data that I'm supposed to get: `{ 'account[username]': "asd", 'account[email]': "asd", ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'` in your `ajax()` settings, otherwise `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is used, which is why you're seeing the data formatted the way you do.

Another possible fix, since the request is sending urlencoded data instead of json (despite `dataType: "json"`), is to set [`extended: true`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#extended) in your `bodyParser.urlencoded()` middleware options on the server side. This will make the parser convert the urlencoded request data such that objects and arrays get created as you're expecting.

Comment: `extended: true` did the trick. Thank-you very much for the help and on the info about what extended does.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to convert the array to a string on the client side and then convert it to a JSON object server side.